# Get execution count of Stored procedure in SQL 2005

Tags: sql-server

We want to capture execution count of selective stored procedure on one of our databases in SQL 2005.

Can anyone please advise, how can we capture the same...with below we only get CACHED SPs data. But in our case, we want for some selective SPs specific to our application

```
SELECT DB_NAME(st.dbid) DBName
      ,OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(st.objectid,dbid) SchemaName
      ,OBJECT_NAME(st.objectid,dbid) StoredProcedure
      ,max(cp.usecounts) Execution_count
 FROM sys.dm_exec_cached_plans cp
         CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(cp.plan_handle) st
 where DB_NAME(st.dbid) is not null and cp.objtype = 'proc'
   group by cp.plan_handle, DB_NAME(st.dbid),
            OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(objectid,st.dbid), 
   OBJECT_NAME(objectid,st.dbid) 
 order by max(cp.usecounts)
```

Comment: AFAIK SQL Server only stores statistics for procedures [in the cache](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280701.aspx).  There is no out of the box solution.

Comment: what does this mean `we want for some selective SPs specific to our application`.Can you plz elaborate on this

Comment: Use a profiler trace.

Comment: by Selective SPs mean just few stored procedures (out of 100 we have in that database)